# Footable fine filtering

Tags: filter, footable

I have this code to have a select field filter through a Footable. It works but it's straining more results than needed. Example: "Article in National Journal" option is filtering rows with both "Article in National Journal" and "Article in International Journal". How can I make it more precise? Thank you.

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#projectos').footable().bind('footable_filtering', function (e) {
      var selected = jQuery('.filter-status').find(':selected').text();
      if (selected && selected.length > 0) {
        e.filter += (e.filter && e.filter.length > 0) ? ' ' + selected : selected;
        e.clear = !e.filter;
      }
    });

    jQuery('.clear-filter').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery('.filter-status').val('');
      jQuery('#projectos').trigger('footable_clear_filter');
    });

    jQuery('.filter-status').change(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery('#projectos').trigger('footable_filter', {filter: jQuery('#filter').val()});
    });
  });
```

Comment: Could you include a JSFiddle or a Plunk?

Comment: It's live here: http://cei.iscte-iul.pt/publicacoes/publicacoes-de-investigadores/

Comment: I provided a simple Plunk in my answer.  I have found that I get answers much faster when I create a simple example using JSFiddle or Plunk. (I personally use plunk more, but both are good)  The live example you provided demonstrated the issue you describe, but it also has a lot of other code that I had to sort through to see just your Footable code.

Answer (score 3):

When Footable filters, it uses the entire text from the whole row and it uses indexof() to test.  You can see this in footable.filter.js in the filterFunction function.

I had to do 3 things to solve the problem.

1. Replace window.footable.options.filter.filterFunction with my own function
2. Do a per column match instead of the whole row.  Depending on the HTML in your row, the spaces between the columns could be lost causing the first word of a column to concatenate with the last word of the previous column.
3. Use a regex match instead of indexof().  This allows you to match a whole word.  As an example, if you us indexof() for "be" in "Don't be evil, because that's not good" will return 6 and 15 even though 15 is the beginning of a completely different word.

Here's the function: (I'm sure there are loads of improvements.  Feel free to edit...)

```
window.footable.options.filter.filterFunction = function(index) {
        var $t = $(this),
          $table = $t.parents('table:first'),
          filter = $table.data('current-filter').toUpperCase(),
          columns = $t.find('td');

        var regEx = new RegExp("\\b" + filter + "\\b");
        var result = false;
        for (i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
          var text = $(columns[i]).text();
          result = regEx.test(text.toUpperCase());
          if (result === true)
            break;

          if (!$table.data('filter-text-only')) {
             text = $(columns[i]).data("value");
             if (text)
               result = regEx.test(text.toString().toUpperCase());
          }

          if (result === true)
            break;
        }

        return result;
      };
```

You can find a plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/P2DWDtyHP3xmoUIcvgDe

Comment: which version of FooTable are you referring to?  I know FT2 is vastly different from FT3...

Comment: This was for V2.